# Facebook event: uninvite all people who are not "attending" nor "maybe"

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I invited 800 friends to a Facebook event I thought would interest only very few people, and the event is getting too popular compared to actual capacity.

Is there any alternative to manually clicking the "X" and "Okay" for hundreds of people?

Can I automatically remove all people who are not "attending" nor "maybe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to do what you are asking.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a javascript snippet doing just this **could** be written.

Answer (score -1):

this tool makes this https://www.facebook.com/EventTool but they charge for it. but their must be a free way or at least a way to program it if they have been able to do this as a facebook 3rd party.

Comment: If I understand well, this app is designed to uninvite-reinvite immediately? As a kind of notification spam I guess. Or can it really uninvite only?

Comment: I have not looked into it in detail - but yes if events are published like a year ahead then it's good to delete people that have not responded and re-invite - if done with respect I would not see this as spam. But I would like to know how it work... you can only invite people you have not yet invited... their is a Firefox plug-in that allows to select all your friends at once when inviting - now this should just work the other way around.